# AngularJS scope variable dont update after database change

Tags: angularjs

I'm doing a Absence Management Web Application. The user need to select the from date and the end date if he want to make a absence request for example for holidays or medical leave. The user have a number of days like 22 and when he select a date will subtract the difference of the dates on the absence days that the user can use.

I'm using angularJS to make http requests to decrement days on database using ASP.NET MVC and after select a date the number will decrement.

Until here no problem! But the problem is, I have displayed the number of absence days on the page, to inform the user and when he select i want that number displayed on view to refresh or update without refresh the page, and that is not happening.

I searched a little bit about that and I saw somenthing like $scope.apply or create a custom service.

One more time, I am using angularJS and i dont know why the scope variable dont refresh after the select date.

What i need to do?

Comment: any code example where you are facing the issue?

Comment: The code its big xD i only can say that i have http request to get the absence days and after select date on calendar and save post on db the absence days will decrement and the problem is after that dont refresh the absence days remaining. But if you want i can add on skype and i can explain better to you understand

Comment: You can create a snippet on https://jsbin.com/?html,js,output  or add me on skype: khairulomi@gmail.com

Comment: ok, I already add you on skype!